# Using overlays for user instruction android

Tags: android, overlay

Hi im trying to add a simple overlay to my app to highlight bits and bobs to the user i am currently following this short guide 
http://www.christianpeeters.com/android-tutorials/android-tutorial-overlay-with-user-instructions/
but i get an error using android studio cannot resolve variable topLeveLayout im a complete beginner and have tried alsorts to get this moving any suggestions?

here is my xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_layout" >


<RelativeLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:text="@string/bath2"
    android:id="@+id/bath_text_View"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/bath_text_View"
    android:contentDescription="@string/bathable2"
    android:src="@drawable/pic5"
    android:layout_above="@+id/nextbutton"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:cropToPadding="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:id="@+id/nextbutton"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="nextImage2"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:clickable="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#88666666"
    android:id="@+id/top_layout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivInstruction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/overlay"
        android:src="@drawable/hint_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

So i have 2 relative layouts in a frame layout the first being my app and the second underneath being the overlay

here is my .java

```
public class bathactivity2 extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bath_2);
    topLevelLayout = findViewById(R.id.top_layout);

    if (isFirstTime()) {
        topLevelLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }



    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);



    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(bathactivity2.this, R.raw.rubber_duck);
            mp.start();
        }
    });

    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(bathactivity2.this, R.raw.bubbles);
            mp.start();
        }
    });

}

public void nextImage2(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BathActivity3.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private boolean isFirstTime()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
    if (!ranBefore) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
        editor.commit();
        topLevelLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        topLevelLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                topLevelLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return false;
            }

        });

    }
    return ranBefore;

}
}
```

it is just an image with a couple of hidden buttons on it hence the reason i would like an overlay to point out where the buttons are, i get errors cannot resolve topLevelLayout cannot resolve motion event and others, is it just a case of declaring these first and if so how? is it something like

```
Layout topLevelLayout;
```

or is there something worse going on here thank you for any help

Comment: why are you using overlay layout?

Comment: Sort of a kids game just an image with hidden buttons on it that make noises when that part of the image is clicked hence the reason i would like an overlay to point out where the buttons are

Comment: you can put buttons in same layout and set their `visibility = gone/invisible`. Thus , your buttons will not be displayed/hidden and you can hadle their `OnClickListener` in activity.

Answer (score 0):

View topLevelLayout;
this solved it